# Loading huge data to sybase using spring jdbctemplate

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm new to spring. I'm working on a batch job that loads the data from a csv file to a sybase table. The input file is more than 5GB & has few millions of records.

I'm doing batch update using spring jdbctemplate. Below is my code snippet.

```
 public int[] batchUpdate(final CsvReader products) throws IOException,
        SQLException {
    int[] updateCounts = getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(sqlStatement,
            new AbstractInterruptibleBatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public boolean setValuesIfAvailable(PreparedStatement pstmt, int i)
                        throws SQLException {

                    // logic to set the values to prepared statement etc...

                                    @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return batchSize;
                }
            });
            }
}
```

I'm using apache dbcp datasource. I set the batchsize to 2000. I did not change  anything else in the defaults for auto-commits etc..

Now, when I run the job.. it takes 4.5 min on an avg to insert 2000 records & the job runs for 2 days(didn't completed yet).

Can anyone suggest how this can be optimized? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do this with Java. Use SyBase's `LOAD TABLE` command and load the data directly. Drop any indexes first and recreate them after the data is loaded. [Reference](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1510/html/iqapgv1/X100956.htm)

Comment: Just to reinforce what HoboSapiens says; when you already have the data in tsv/csv format, it's going to be way more effective to use a load tool to write to the DB. (e.g. in postgres, use `COPY`). Even if you need to manipulate the data, it's usually going to be better to load all the data first, then run `UPDATE` or even create new tables based on the loaded data rather than running it through a layer of java code.

Comment: @Deinum, thanks for the response. Are you asking me to use bcp utility to load the data? Because, in this case there are only specific fields from the csv file that I need to load to the table. The csv file has 300+ fields out of which I need only 36 columns. I don't know how to specify bcp to use only those fields(using column names/numbers).